# Esformatter - Ignoring JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am struck looking for a way to ignore JSX while using esformatter .... 
[esformatter-jsx-ignore](https://github.com/royriojas/esformatter-jsx-ignore) wont work because of es6 imports in my project and making formatJSX = false of [esformatter-jsx](https://github.com/royriojas/esformatter-jsx) can't be used either as it just disables the esformatter-jsx plugin.